# ImageView isn't displayed

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout but the ImageView with `@id/category_starred_icon` is not showed, the expected behavoir is expand the LinearLayout with the 2 TextView to all empty space avalaible, but the ImageView isn't showed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/borders" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/category_color"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@color/awazari_blue" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/category_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:hint="@string/app_name"  />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/category_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textIsSelectable="false"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/awazari_medium_gray"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:hint="@string/description" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/category_starred_icon"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:src="@drawable/unstarred"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

use the below code it will exactly gave you what you want :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"

android:padding="6dip">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"                   
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="First Textview" />

    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"             
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:text="Second Textview" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"        
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is the output:

[image]

hope this help you .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want without a screenshot or a description but your problem is that your `ImageView` is inside a `LienarLayout` with `horizontal orientation` who has another child `LinearLayout` with a `horizontal orientation` who's `width` is `match_parent`, leaving no room for the `ImageView`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"    <!-- This is the ImageViews parent  -->
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"         <!-- This child is taking up all of the width  -->
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

There are different things you can do here depending on what you want like removing one of the `LinearLayout`s or giving it a `vertical orientation` or using a `RelativeLayout`. But I don't know what exactly you want so its hard to give a complete answer on that

**Edit**

You can see if this gives you what you want. Without a screenshot or better description its hard to know exactly where you want everything. But you could tweak this to your liking

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"     //changed this to a RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"    // changed the width here
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/category_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="Text"  />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/category_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:ellipsize="end" 
            android:text="Text Again"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/category_starred_icon"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:src="@drawable/blue_box"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Note that I changed the text of `TextView`s, colors, and backgrounds just so I could display it on my editor

Comment: i need display the image to the right of the LinearLayout with the two TextView

Comment: Then you can use `weight` or give your child `LinearLayout` a `width` of `wrap_content`

Comment: if a put wrap_content on the LinearLayout the ImageView is not show in the right side

Comment: See my edit. I'm not sure if that's exactly what you want or not. It keeps the `TextView`s where they are and puts the `ImageView` to the right of the screen

Comment: with this changes I try and (if the text is short) the ImageView is show in the middle i need show always to the right

Comment: Compare it again. With the `RelativeLayout` and `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` on the `ImageView` it will always be all the way to the right. If you need to, you can post the updated xml so I can see if you are missing something

Answer (score 0):

Your `ImageView` is hidden because you are using `android:orientation="horizontal"` both with layout with `android:layout_width="match_parent"`.

It has hidden your `ImageView` on the right side of inner `LinearLayout` which is not visible.

You can use `android:weight=1` to fill all free space apart of `ImageView` by `LinearLayout`.